# SQL Count() not giving desired results

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I am having some difficulties figuring out this SQL statement.

Here is the schema of the table.

```
studentID |subjectID | attendanceStatus | classDate | 
1234567      ...           1               .....
1234567      ...           0
```

Basically I want to count the attendance percentage based on the studentID and display them in columns like this

```
studentID | subjectID | attendancePercentage
```

attendancePercentage is the number of 0s / total entries for that student

Here is what I did and it wasn't giving the desired results.

```
SELECT studentID, COUNT(attendanceStatus =  0) AS Absent,
COUNT( attendanceStatus = 1) As Present
FROM attendance WHERE studentID = '1234567';
```

That failed.

I hope that I made sense of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: In any DBMS except MySQL, you would need a GROUP BY clause listing every non-aggragate column in the select-list.  It would still be correct in MySQL; it probably isn't 100% necessary.

Comment: A statement 'that failed' is not very helpful; it would be better to state what result you got, and why it was wrong.  Or, in some cases, the error message that you got (and the problem was, presumably, that you got the error instead of a decent result).

Comment: Thank you. I will try to be more specific next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need use sum instead.

```
SELECT  studentID ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN attendanceStatus = 0 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS Absent ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN attendanceStatus = 1 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS Present
FROM    attendance
WHERE   studentID = '1234567'
```

Comment: I would collapse each of those SUM expressions onto one line.  I think in MySQL you could simply use `SUM(attendanceStatus = 0)` and `SUM(attendanceStatus = 1)` and you'd get the correct result without the CASE expression.